# find-system-path

Tags: racket

I am trying to determine the location of `.rackettrc` on Windows using the following command:

```
(find-system-path 'init)
```

as specified in the Racket documentation. However, I keep getting the error message

```
expects argument of type <system-path-symbol>: given 'init.
```

Is this a bug in Racket or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Ah. I realized I was looking at the old documentation.
`find-system-path` now works now as follows:

```
(find-system-path 'init-file)
```